# Clair startup error grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, clair

I am trying to run the clair docker image `quay.io/coreos/clair-git:latest` using docker-compose.  when start the container it started throwing this message. not getting any response for name space query `curl -v http://localhost:6060/v1/namespaces`  getting 404.

```
clair_1  | {"Event":"pagination key is empty, generating...","Level":"warning","Location":"config.go:110","Time":"2018-02-08 20:46:49.733074"}
clair_1  | {"Detectors":"apt-sources,lsb-release,os-release,redhat-release,alpine-release","Event":"Clair registered components","Level":"info","Listers":"apk,dpkg,rpm","Location":"main.go:103","Time":"2018-02-08 20:46:49.733721","Updaters":"alpine,debian,oracle,rhel,ubuntu"}
clair_1  | {"Event":"running database migrations","Level":"info","Location":"pgsql.go:270","Time":"2018-02-08 20:46:49.739997"}
clair_1  | {"Event":"database migration ran successfully","Level":"info","Location":"pgsql.go:277","Time":"2018-02-08 20:46:49.744277"}
clair_1  | {"Event":"starting grpc server","Level":"info","Location":"server.go:155","Time":"2018-02-08 20:46:49.744700","addr":"[::]:6060"}
clair_1  | {"Event":"grpc server is configured without client certificate authentication","Level":"warning","Location":"server.go:199","Time":"2018-02-08 20:46:49.745422"}
clair_1  | {"Event":"notifier service is disabled","Level":"info","Location":"notifier.go:76","Time":"2018-02-08 20:46:49.745800"}
clair_1  | 2018/02/08 20:46:49 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp [::]:6060: connect: network is unreachable"; Reconnecting to {[::]:6060 <nil>}
clair_1  | {"Event":"starting health API","Level":"info","Location":"api.go:62","Time":"2018-02-08 20:46:49.746259","addr":"0.0.0.0:6061"}
clair_1  | {"Event":"updater service started","Level":"info","Location":"updater.go:91","Time":"2018-02-08 20:46:49.746437","lock identifier":"911feae4-9a65-4317-9676-8c65f4404e76"}
clair_1  | 2018/02/08 20:46:50 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp [::]:6060: connect: network is unreachable"; Reconnecting to {[::]:6060 <nil>}
clair_1  | 2018/02/08 20:46:52 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp [::]:6060: connect: network is unreachable"; Reconnecting to {[::]:6060 <nil>}
clair_1  | 2018/02/08 20:46:55 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp [::]:6060: connect: network is unreachable"; Reconnecting to {[::]:6060 <nil>}
```

Here is my working `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  clair:
    container_name: clair_clair
    image: quay.io/coreos/clair:v2.0.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "6060-6061:6060-6061"
    volumes:
      - /tmp:/tmp
      - ./clair_config:/config
    command: [-config, /config/config.yaml]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the stable image instead: `quay.io/coreos/clair:v2.0.1` I noticed the same errors until I changed the image.